# SQL get first and last hours in a day

Tags: sql

I am a large `Google Cloud Big Query` dataset with 2 columns, `date and score`. `Date` is a `string` and `score` an `int` The date format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` and the score is an `integer` from 0 to 100. I need to create a `SQL` statement to get the score from the first hour of the day (always `00:00:00`) and the last hour of the day (always `23:00:00`). I cannot split the column `date` to get the hour in a different column.

**Example**

```
2020-10-17 00:00:00    54
2020-10-17 01:00:00    76
2020-10-17 02:00:00    43
...
2020-10-17 21:00:00    28
2020-10-17 22:00:00    15
2020-10-17 23:00:00    19
```

I should get 54 and 19

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What data type is the column `date`?

Comment: What if some hours are missing for a day e.g. 04:00 through 05:00 are missing would you use 06:00 instead?

Comment: There will be always 23:00:00 (last hour) and 00:00:00 (first hour). You are right about the edges cases but I will consider it after I find a general solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A date in string format `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` is comparable, so there is no need to cast it to a date.
You can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function and a string function like `substring()`, or an equivalent for your database, to get the date part of the string:

```
select distinct substring(date, 1, 10) as date,
       first_value(score) over (partition by substring(date, 1, 10) order by date) min_score,
       first_value(score) over (partition by substring(date, 1, 10) order by date desc) max_score
from tablename
```

Comment: Do you know how can I just get the `min_date` and `max_date` from that rather that getting both min and max  for every `date`?

Comment: If you mean the minimum and maximum of all dates in the table: `select min(substring(date, 1, 10)) min_date, max(substring(date, 1, 10)) max_date from tablename`

Answer (score 1):

Databases have some way to convert a datetime value to a date.  Then you can use something like this:

```
select cast(date as date),
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then score end) as score_first,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then score end) as score_last
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by cast(date as date) order by date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(date as date) order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by cast(date as date);
```

Note:  This exact syntax may not work in all databases because the syntax may need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, date, 108) in ('00:00:00', '23:00:00')
```

Comment: Please add some commentary to help the person who wrote the question to also understand how the code works.